# ideavim action name for "convert to block body" and "convert to expression body"

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, ideavim

I would like to know, if by any chance, is it possible to have below actions mapped via ideavim:
"convert to block body"
"convert to expression body"
example:
move to { of a function, type \f and the expression body is converted to block body, similarly for block body to expression body. I specifically want this for flutter. I am using android studio.

block body:

```
setState(() {
    foo=bar;
});
```

expression body:

`setState(() => foo=bar);`

Comment: there are no dedicated actions for Dart intentions AFAIK. See https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#finding-actions, https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/src/com/maddyhome/idea/vim/package-info.java for more info

Comment: @lena Can we make use of GUI actions? like send alt+enter and then down arrow?

Answer (score 0):

A key binding for intentions might be as close as you can get. In Settings→Keymap it's called "Show Context Actions". You can bind it to a VIM sequence in your `~/.ideavimrc` like this:

```
nnoremap <leader><CR> :action ShowIntentionActions<CR>
```

Once you are in the context actions menu, you can use the keyboard to search and  to activate. So you can probably select the actions you're looking for by typing "block" or "inline" and then hitting return.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The action you are pointing to, is already possible via `option`+`enter`. This solution hardly reduces any keystroke. old: `option` + `enter`. new: `<leader>`f. Rest of the steps are same in both the cases. This does not solve the problem.

Comment: Agreed, this answer doesn't save any keybindings. But it might be useful if you prefer using the leader-style, multiple sequential keystroke bindings with IdeaVIM, rather than the modifer+single key bindings of regular IntelliJ. 

I got used to this style with Spacemacs and have been using it in my ~/.vimrc, and am starting to replace my modifier-heavy IntelliJ bindings with this style. I find it is easier to memorize.